# Почему не работает $('#myDiv').click(function(){})?

Tags: html, jquery

Есть ссылка, представленная на сайте как картинка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: 1]]

Повесил на неё такой скриптик:

```
$('#header_logo').click(function(){
   alert("eqw");
}
```

Но при клике на изображение просто происходит выполнение действия ссылки, т.е. переход по href. Никакого алерта нет, вообще. Тоже самое я пробовал сделать и с заголовками даже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но рез-ат не изменяется. Шотакое?

---

### UPD

Спасибо **Grundy**, уже в который раз! :)
Проблема была и в синтаксисе (мои глаза...) и, видимо, в функции:

```
 $('#page_header').on('click', function(event){
   alert("eqw");
 });
```

Comment: функция добавления обработчика вызывается раньше чем в разметке появляется нужный элемент, на странице несколько элементов с одинаковы id и вы просто кликаете не на тот

Comment: она ведь вызывается только при клике на конкретный элемент.
я кликаю только тогда, когда страница полностью подгрузилась.

Comment: она вызывается, если добавлена, если в момент добавления этого элемента еще нет, она и не добавится, и, соответственно, не вызовется

Comment: кажется, понял)

Comment: а как можно отсрочить вызов функции добавления?

Comment: вообще зависит от того, что происходит на странице

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('#header_logo').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("eqw");
}
```